# JavaFX ListView Type Conflict

Tags: java, listview, javafx-8

So I have a ListView that contains Tasks. A Task is composed of a title, description, and urgency, all of which are Strings. What I would like to have happen is that the ListView displays the titles of the tasks it contains. However, I cannot simply switch my ListView to be over Strings, because I need to be able to access the underlying Task object when the task is selected in my GUI. Thus, in my current implementation, the items that appear in the ListView are references to the Task objects (eg, todoList.model.Task@19a4c32f), rather than the title of the Task (eg, "Do Laundry"). Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look at the  [`cellFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#cellFactoryProperty) (or in other words: cell renderer) functionality of the `ListView`?

There are plenty of good tutorials out there, like on [Oracles site](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm).

But the point is

1. Store your data in the `ListView`
2. The cell renderer creates a Text and / or graphic representation of your data.